# Limitations on .stl file importing

Tags: import, file-format

I have `.stl` data files that I'm trying to import into Blender. Large, over 100MB. I'm having trouble importing them, and I'm wondering if the size might be the reason. They all return the following error lines upon attempting import:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.57\scripts\addons\io_mesh_stl\__init__.py", line 86, in execute
    paths = [os.path.join(self.directory, name.name) for name in self.files]
  File "C:\...\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.57\scripts\addons\io_mesh_stl\__init__.py", line 86, in <listcomp>
    paths = [os.path.join(self.directory, name.name) for name in self.files]
  File "C:\...\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.57\scripts\modules\bpy_types.py", line 626, in __getattribute__
    return getattr(properties, attr)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xee in position 27: invalid continuation byte

location:<unknown location>:-1
```

Comment: This looks like a bug report, can you give a link to a file that fails to import?

Comment: @ideasman42 the files aren't public

Comment: @JNF it looks too much like a bug and without the files, we will just be here speculating. Voted to close.

Comment: @iKlsR, agreeing. Something with version 2.57 that worked out when I upgraded

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your having some sort of corruption with your binary ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552555/unicodedecodeerror-invalid-continuation-byte)). Change the settings of your import or reexporting the model should fix it.

Comment: Can't reexport - it's data received from elsewhere. Sounds funny all files are corrupted. Can there maybe be differences in the `.stl` standard itself?

Comment: @JNF scratch that. I'm guessing its an import then. The wikipedia page says that there are two types of STL files. ASCII and binary. I'm guessing there's an option to import binary?

Comment: Good point. Can't find such an option on the interface (blender 2.57). I'd be glad to check if that can solve the issue. Tell me if you find it...

Comment: Here's the troubleshoot/bug page: http://projects.blender.org/tracker/?func=detail&atid=469&aid=22837&group_id=153

Comment: I see someone addressing the issue there. But I'm not sure how to use his code

Comment: Ok, it looks like he patched it. If you get a development build, it might be fixed. You can download a build from: http://builder.blender.org/download

Comment: Updated to latest version. It presumably does the import. I end up with a blank viewport